# My Boss owes money but I am named on letter from debt collection agency (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, small-business, debt

My employer has an outstanding debt with a company he aked me to speak with a couple of years ago. Now that company has my name listed as a "contact". He received a letter from a debt collection agency in regard his failure to pay them however, although it was sent to his business adresss, it had my name on it. I am concerned that this may now effect my credit rating so I asked him to phone them and remove my name, but they wouldnt. They said I was only a "contact" but I am still concerned. Any advice would be much appreciated. I am in the UK. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your credit report to see if it's on it?

Comment: I did a soft search and it seems ok...for now....However it is a Limited company, so am I correct in thinking that the companies debt/credit rating will not effect me as an individual. I am not a director just an employee, I just dont like that a debt collection agency has my name though and I am still worried as I am rather ignorant how it all works.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would not be overly concerned unless they started contacting you directly on your personal time or it showed up on your credit report.

It is very likely that you are listed simply for their own records. This is correct for them to do, since you spoke to them in the past as an agent of your company. There should not be any legal connection to your personal finances.

If it continues to be a concern, I would question whether I wanted to work for such an employer. I do not know your entire situation, but this kind of misbehavior is a red flag if not addressed.

Answer (score 0):

You havent signed a contract, so you are only an authorised contact so you have nothing to worry about at all.  Your credit reference can only be affected if you are a signed party on the contract.  I would imagine that they wont remove your details as you may assist them by contacting your emplorer, and effectively chase the debt for them especially if you seem to be family member or a friend of the business owner.
How did you find out about the debt, did they phone you?  If you really want peace of mind, you could write to them and confirm that you are not authorised to be contacted by phone or in writing regarding the debt, and that you are not in anyway liable for the debt and that your contact details must be put beyond use, and as you are concerned, say that if they take any further action against you such as affect your credit ref etc then you will take them to 'your' local magistrates court to seek compensation.  Use strong terms and insist they must do what you ask rather than just say that you would like something done etc.  Say that you 'Will' take further action which is generic, and that you 'May' do specific things so that it sounds strong but you haven't have committed to any thing in particular.  This would most likely be more than enough to stop further contact.